# Is this string instrument making a trill sound?

Tags: instrumental, technique

https://youtu.be/H8e0PFMo_6E?list=LL8veiH4tExKaroj4Tif84cw&t=530

8:50~8:53
is this sound a trill? what bowing technique is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a trill, but a [tremolo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tremolo) or "trembling sound".  It has the effect of a single sustained note, but it is caused by bowing back and forth very rapidly, and with very small motions.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. Every time,  I get impressed with how knowledgeable you are and it really helps me.

Comment: A trill is a rapid alternation of 2 adjacent notes whereas a tremolo is a single note or a chord played as described in the answer